# ちいとばかし苦しいから extra cash to make ends meet

Tags: syntax, reading-comprehension

> ティーゼル:
>
> うぐっ！まだ潰れちゃいねえよ
>   今月の運転資金が、ちいとばかし苦しいから
>   軽くバイトするだけのこったよ

Teisel: Gaahh! No, it hasn't gone under! We're just, a little in the red this 
month, that's all! Just need a little extra cash to make ends meet!

Response I received from someone:
Guuu! I’m not bankrupted yet.

I’m just having a bit of a hard time getting some working capital.

I'll just do a bit of part-time work.

軽く = light, a little

バイト = part time job

するだけのこったよ（= するだけのことだよ） = only just do

So I'm only just confused about
ちいとばかし苦しいから
I've never read or heard ちいとばかし before so please explain this.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ちいと](http://19113be104ef68ba6094f31cd078121957609d7b2e189c575dc271cfeda9d93e) (ちっと) is a colloquial and a little dialectal variant of ちょっと. ばかし is a colloquial variant of ばかり.

So ちいとばかし is the same as ちょっとばかり or ちょっとだけ ("only a little bit").